# Comparing Order of 2 Python Lists

Tags: python, string, list

I am looking for some help comparing the order of 2 Python lists, **list1** and **list2**, to detect when **list2** is out of order.

- **list1** is static and contains the strings `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j`. This is the "correct" order.
- **list2** contains the same strings, but the order and the number of strings may change. (e.g. `a,b,f,d,e,g,c,h,i,j` or  `a,b,c,d,e`)

I am looking for an efficient way to detect when **list2** is our of order by comparing it against **list1**.

For example, if **list2** is `a,c,d,e,g,i` should return true (as the strings are in order)

While, if **list2** is `a,d,b,c,e` should return false (as string d appears out of order)

Comment: Since `list1` is always in alphabetical order, I'm wondering if you need to check `list2` against it all. Would it work if you simplied checked if `list2` is in alphabetical order of itself?

Answer (score 8):

First, let's define `list1`:

```
>>> list1='a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j'.split(',')
>>> list1
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

While your `list1` happens to be in alphabetical order,  we will *not* assume that.  This code works regardless.

Now, let's create a `list2` that is out-of-order:

```
>>> list2 = 'a,b,f,d,e,g,c,h,i,j'.split(',')
>>> list2
['a', 'b', 'f', 'd', 'e', 'g', 'c', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

Here is how to test whether `list2` is out of order or not:

```
>>> list2 == sorted(list2, key=lambda c: list1.index(c))
False
```

`False` means out-of-order.

Here is an example that is in order:

```
>>> list2 = 'a,b,d,e'.split(',')
>>> list2 == sorted(list2, key=lambda c: list1.index(c))
True
```

`True` means in-order.

#### Ignoring elements of list1 not in list2

Let's consider a `list2` that has an element not in `list1`:

```
>>> list2 = 'a,b,d,d,e,z'.split(',')
```

To ignore the unwanted element, let's create `list2b`:

```
>>> list2b = [c for c in list2 if c in list1]
```

We can then test as before:

```
>>> list2b == sorted(list2b, key=lambda c: list1.index(c))
True
```

#### Alternative not using `sorted`

```
>>> list2b = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'e']
>>> indices = [list1.index(c) for c in list2b]
>>> all(c <= indices[i+1] for i, c in enumerate(indices[:-1]))
True
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you. One more question: if list2 contains a string that is not in list1, how can I ignore that?

Comment: @chasm Glad it worked.  Only one more line of code is needed to handle the unwanted strings.  See updated answer.

Comment: All those `index` calls can get extremely expensive (quadratic time!), and the sort is an inefficient way to tell whether the input is already sorted.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to compare it to `list1` since it seems like `list1` is in alphabetical order? Can't you do the following?

```
def is_sorted(alist):
    return alist == sorted(alist)

print is_sorted(['a','c','d','e','g','i'])
# True

print is_sorted(['a','d','b','c','e'])
# False
```

Comment: This would work, however, list2 is dynamic and changes frequently.

Comment: Assuming that `list1` is always the same as outlined in your question, then I think this is the simplest answer. What you really need to do is just check if `list2` is in alphabetical order unto itself, and this function will always check that for any list of alphabetical characters you pass to it.

Comment: We can't assume that items in list1 are in the lexicographical order in the general case. If we could then there wouldn't be the question. If the list2 is very large then instead `sorted()`-based solution the ordinary `issorted` could be linear in time and terminate earlier: `issorted  = lambda L: all(x < y for x,y in pairwise(L))`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that runs in expected linear time. That isn't too important if `list1` is always 10 elements and `list2` isn't any longer, but with longer lists, solutions based on `index` will experience extreme slowdowns.

First, we preprocess `list1` so we can quickly find the index of any element. (If we have multiple `list2`s, we can do this once and then use the preprocessed output to quickly determine whether multiple `list2`s are sorted):

```
list1_indices = {item: i for i, item in enumerate(list1)}
```

Then, we check whether each element of `list2` has a lower index in `list1` than the next element of `list2`:

```
is_sorted = all(list1_indices[x] < list1_indices[y] for x, y in zip(list2, list2[1:]))
```

We can do better with `itertools.izip` and `itertools.islice` to avoid materializing the whole `zip` list, letting us save a substantial amount of work if we detect that `list2` is out of order early in the list:

```
# On Python 3, we can just use zip. islice is still needed, though.
from itertools import izip, islice
is_sorted = all(list1_indices[x] < list1_indices[y]
                for x, y in izip(list2, islice(list2, 1, None)))
```

Comment: Have you tried to measure how large list2 should be that the  itertools solution becomes faster? The same for `is_sorted = lambda L: L == sorted(L, key=rank.__getitem__)` where `rank = list1_indices`—it might be adequate for small lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
is_sorted = not any(list1.index(list2[i]) > list1.index(list2[i+1]) for i in range(len(list2)-1))
```

The function `any` returns true if any of the items in an iterable are true. I combined this with a generator expression that loops through all the values of list2 and makes sure they're in order according to list1.

Answer (score 0):

```
if list2 == sorted(list2,key=lambda element:list1.index(element)):
    print('sorted')
```

Comment: Your first revision was flawed

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that when you are writing that list1 is strings a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i that this means that a could be 'zebra' and string b could actually be 'elephant' so the order may not be alphabetical. Also, this approach will return false if an item is in list2 but not in list1.

```
good_list2 = ['a','c','d','e','g','i']

bad_list2 = ['a','d','b','c','e']

def verify(somelist):
    list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
    while len(list1) > 0:
        try:
            list1 = list1[:list1.index(somelist.pop())]
        except ValueError:
            return False
    return True
```